# Is it safe to use a type of sync.Map?

Tags: go, concurrency

I would like to define types of sync.Map so that I can have some type checking and basically isolate the interface{} use. Is it safe to use sync.Map like this ?

```
type WalletMap sync.Map

var walletMap = &WalletMap{}

func (m *WalletMap) LoadOrStore(key string, value *CoinMap) (actual *CoinMap, loaded bool) {
    itf, ok := (*sync.Map)(m).LoadOrStore(key, value)
    if !ok {
        return nil, ok
    }
    return itf.(*CoinMap), ok

}

func (m *WalletMap) Load(key string) (actual *CoinMap, loaded bool) {
    itf, ok := (*sync.Map)(m).Load(key)
    if !ok {
        return nil, ok
    }
    return itf.(*CoinMap), ok

}
```

Comment: Sure, the important part about `sync.Map` is not to copy it. The rest is ok. It might be better to make it a field (named or not) in your `WalletMap` though, it's clearer.

Comment: There is hardly anything special (magic) behind golang standard libs, so just treat them as normal go code.

Comment: @Marc I believe (*sync.Map)(m) is a copy, right?

Comment: @Books: that's a copy of a pointer. Why not avoid the confusion altogether, and just put a `sync.Map` into a new struct type?